# c# Compare two text files and generate a new one with differences

Tags: c#, file, text, compare

I am looking for the best way to compare 2 text files (+-15000lines) quickly and get as output strings that are differents in the two files.
1st one is an old inventory, new one is the current inventory and I would like to generate an third one containing strings that are different between file2 & file1. (95% of the 2 files will be similar).

Comment: Can you describe what "similar" means in this case? And do you need to do this programmatically, or you just want a tool to do a diff (like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org))?

Comment: It will be mainly the same in the same order but items may be missing, the goal is to do it programmatically, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Very simple approach, assuming that *similar* means *equal*:

```
var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(file1Path);
var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(file2Path);
IEnumerable<String> inFirstNotInSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines);
IEnumerable<String> inSecondNotInFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines);
```

You can use `foreach` to enumerate the lines.

Comment: If the assumption proves to be correct by the OP, I will upvote

Comment: Note that you need to materialize the query for example via `ToList()` or use `File.ReadAllLines` instead to avoid an `ObjectDisposedException` if you want to use both sequences. The `File.ReadLines` streams the lines  and once you've finished the underlying stream gets closed. I'm showing `ReadLines` nevertheless because it's the best choice in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Isn't there a performance difference between ReadLines & ReadAllLines ? If no difference for a file of 15000l I will use readAllLines, Thanks

Comment: @OwenS: There's a great difference: `ReadLines` will stream the lines(like a `Streamreader`) whereas `ReadAllLines` will read **all** lines into a `String[]`(in memory). So the first won't use memory and the second puts all into memory. So if you have enough memory and the file is not too large  you can use `File.ReadAllLines`. Note that memory consumption and _performance_ are not necessarily related.

Comment: i know this is an old question, but how will you deal with large files for example 1 gig or more? i tried this answer and ended up out of memory exception specially when working with ienumerable

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) diff library from Google. Look at the diff_main method that takes the 2 strings and returns a list of differences.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The library is now available at https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch

Answer (score 1):

If the output is in the same order, compare lines directly. You may need to skip line when the value is missing in the other file.

If, however, the output is not the same, then you might need to load the files into memory and look up the relevant inventory item from one file in to the other. Then do whatever you need when not-found or different.

Comment: +1 If the order is unchanged, the algorithm should be fairly simple and efficient.

Comment: The inventory mainly contains directory listing with parameters, if a file have been removed, there will be a missing item but the order is the same, thanks.